# SQLite3 WHERE Clause In Python

Tags: python, sqlite, where-clause

Just recently ran into a problem running python 3.3 using SQLite3. I've created a fairly large table so I'll just use a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE X(omega TEXT, z TEXT, id INT);
```

Now, I'm using various functions to access this table from a main script. In one of the functions I have the code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?",Omega)
```

This works just fine when I have the Omega variable set as a one-character string. However, when I increase the number of characters (ex. if Omega='10'), then I get the following error:

```
    cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?",Omega)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Now, I HAVE found a workaround:

```
cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega="+Omega)
```

but I'd like to know why this works and the "proper" method of using a question mark doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?",(Omega,))
```

since a string is iterable it tries to bind each letter to a ? (eg it sees `cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?",('1','0'))` instead of `cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?",('10',))`

if you specify like this it knows the string is one item that binds to the question mark

Answer (score 5):

According to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), the second parameter to `execute()` should be a tuple. Presumably the bindings are using duck-typing, and since a string acts like a tuple, it gets treated like one. You can fix this by changing the second parameter to a tuple:

```
cur.execute("SELECT omega,z FROM X WHERE omega=?", (Omega,))
```